# SendBird - Channel list query filtered by date of last change (property updatedAt)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sendbird

I'm trying to persist my channel list locally, so I need to find out a way to query only channels that has been updated after my last "activity".

Group Channel has lastMessage property, which indicates when last message (if it exists) was received. How can I fetch new channels that was created or updated after most recent last massage?

Currently, I load my channels with the snippet below:

```
self.channelsListQuery = [SBDGroupChannel createMyGroupChannelListQuery];
[self.channelsListQuery setIncludeEmptyChannel: NO];
[self.channelsListQuery setOrder: (SBDGroupChannelListOrderLatestLastMessage)];

[self.channelsListQuery loadNextPageWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray<SBDGroupChannel*> *_Nullable channels, SBDError* _Nullable error) {

    // My stuff...
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `getNextMessagesByTimestamp:limit:reverse:messageType:customType:completionHandler:` which takes timestamp as a param.

```
[self.channel getNextMessagesByTimestamp:yourLatestStoredTs limit:30 reverse:NO completionHandler:^(NSArray<SBDBaseMessage *> * _Nullable messages, SBDError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                // Error!
                return;
            }
}];
```

Comment: I think You didn't understand me. I want to get channel list with all changed group channels after my most recent last message on my local data. In your example, I need to get messages from one specific channel, I think It would ignore new group channel conversations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement to sort Group channels by latest activity and used the Sort() method on the channel array to solve this problem.

Once the channels array of [SBDGroupChannel] is populated and right before the tableview is reloaded, sort the array.

This sorted my group channels by the latest first.

```
self.groupChannelListQuery = SBDGroupChannel.createMyGroupChannelListQuery()
    self.groupChannelListQuery?.limit = 20
    self.groupChannelListQuery?.order = 
                  SBDGroupChannelListOrder.latestLastMessage

    self.groupChannelListQuery?.loadNextPage(completionHandler: { (channels, error) in
        if error != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            }

            return
        }

        self.channels.removeAll()
        self.cachedChannels = false

        for channel in channels! {
            self.channels.append(channel)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.channels.count == 0 {
                self.tableView.separatorStyle = 
                  UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
                self.noChannelLabel.isHidden = false
            }
            else {
                self.tableView.separatorStyle = 
                       UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.singleLine
                self.noChannelLabel.isHidden = true
            }

            **self.channels.sort(by: { (channelA, channelB) -> Bool in 
                  return channelA.createdAt > channelB.createdAt 
             })**
            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
```